# Is there an alternative to the proprietary ActiveXObject in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mozilla, activexobject

Is there a general alternative to IE's proprietary `ActiveXObject` in JavaScript. Lacking such a general alternative, is there a method to use COM Objects with Mozilla?

The reason for the question is that I'd like to have an equivalent to

```
var conObj = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
```

with mozilla (for local use).

Comment: Why not fetch the data server-side?

Comment: Because I hoped I could put the query into a html/javascript file and distribute it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to COM for Mozilla that's available to non plugin code.
Plugins can use [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM).

If you want something like ADODB.Connection, take a look at the new HTML5 local storage APIs.  There's a good tutorial at http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/

Comment: It's not that I want to *store* data, but I want to display existing data (in a corporate database). It seems as though this cannot be done without XPCOM.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, a lot of the things that you can do with ActiveX can be done with [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/)

Comment: FYI, [Gears is no longer supported](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html).

Comment: oh, I had no idea. Thanks for sharing!